# Conflicts between identical handlers in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, and have recently started to see a very large number of console error messages regarding conflicting handlers, such as the following:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-22 08:57:41.828
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.UndoActionHandler@7df5358)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.UndoActionHandler@7df5358)}
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.ui code=4 Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.UndoActionHandler@7df5358)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.UndoActionHandler@7df5358)} null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-22 08:57:42.625
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@62ccbd95)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@62ccbd95)}
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.ui code=4 Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@62ccbd95)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@62ccbd95)} null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-22 08:57:43.100
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)}
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.ui code=4 Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)} null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-22 08:57:43.581
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)}
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.ui code=4 Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@135ddb56)} null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-22 08:57:43.595
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.move: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)}
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.ui code=4 Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.move: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)} null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-22 08:57:44.015
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.move: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)}
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.ui code=4 Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.move: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction@6859bbd4)} null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-22 08:57:44.026
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.RenameResourceAction@7d836c4a)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.RenameResourceAction@7d836c4a)}
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.ui code=4 Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.RenameResourceAction@7d836c4a)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.RenameResourceAction@7d836c4a)} null
```

Notably, these are all platform-defined handlers and the conflicts appear to happen between each handler and itself, which is puzzling to say the least.

All errors appear when I click on entries in the Project Explorer view in my application. As I click around, the responsiveness of the Project Explorer degrades, up to the point where the context menu is no longer popping up.

My application is running in compatibility mode on version 4.5 of the Eclipse platform.

Another detail, which may or may not be relevant, is that I started seeing these messages after installing the VisualVM Eclipse plugin. I have uninstalled it, but still see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the problem and was able to fix it.

One of the new items I added to the Project Explorer context menu relies on a `PropertyTester` to decide when it should be shown. This tester was very slow (taking a few seconds to execute) due to an implementation bug, which apparently caused the handler resolution problems.

Drastically improving the performance of the `PropertyTester` resulted in these error messages not being shown anymore, and the Project Explorer working normally again.

Comment: may I know what do you mean by implementation bug and what have you done to improve performance here?